# recursive function in python that returns copy of list given as argument with a's replaced by b's and does not alter the list given as argument

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function the will take a list of numbers and two integers a and b, and would return a copy of the list -but in this copy, all a in the list of numbers given as argument will be replaced by b. I have written this code, but after running from shell, it is showing "None" (without double quotes)

```
def replace(thelist,a,b):
    assert type(thelist)==list, `thelist` + ' is not a list'

    assert type(a)==int, `a` + ' is not an integer'

    assert type(b)==int, `b` + ' is not an integer'
    if len(thelist)==0:
        return []
    return ([b] if thelist[0]==a else [thelist[0]]).append(replace(thelist[1:],a,b))
```

Comment: Note that the `\`backtick\`` syntax is deprecated in favor of `repr(backtick)`

Comment: Also, `len(thelist) == 0` is unpythonic, and better spelt `not thelist`

Comment: Final nitpick: you shouldn't really be type checking here, at least not for `a` and `b` - there's no reason your function should be restricted to `int`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use '+' instead of .append. You were getting None because e.g. [10].append([2]) returns None.

```
def replace(thelist,a,b):

 assert type(thelist)==list, `thelist` + ' is not a list'

 assert type(a)==int, `a` + ' is not an integer'

 assert type(b)==int, `b` + ' is not an integer'
 if len(thelist)==0:
     return []
 return ([b] if thelist[0]==a else [thelist[0]])+replace(thelist[1:],a,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def replace(lst, a, b):
    if not lst:
        return []
    head, tail = lst[0], lst[1:]
    return [b if head == a else head] + replace(tail, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def replace(thelist,a,b):
    # assert stuff...
    if len(thelist)==0: return []
    if thelist[0] == a: r = [b] 
    else: r = [thelist[0]]
    return r + replace(thelist[1:], a, b)

print replace([1,2,3,1,3,4,1,2], 1, 10)
```

Gives:

```
[10, 2, 3, 10, 3, 4, 10, 2]
```